# What is the best way to format strings in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am currently reading books and taking online courses on Python. There are numerous ways we can format strings in python, but I was wondering what is the best way.

For example if we have this two ways of formating strings, which one would be better to use? Does it even make a difference?

```
    print("I am %d years old." % (age))
```

or

```
    print("I am {} years old".format(age))
```

or maybe even

```
    print("I am " + str(age) + " years old")
```

Well anyway, it's more a theoretical question. I am new to coding, but I know some functions or methods are more memory consuming than others, so I am trying to figure out if maybe one of these is a better practice.

Comment: I prefer your first example.  I have found "format" to be expensive if called too often, and try to avoid it as a result - the c style %d etc has been more efficient for me.  Readability is usually king though - the named parameters appoach is best for code that is going to have multiple viewers and updates...

Comment: You have demonstrated "old-style", "new-style" and "ugly-style". You missed the new `f` strings.

Comment: The last is the *worst* option, as each use of `+` creates a separate temporary `str` object; the other two create just one, no matter how many placeholders might be replaced with extra strings.

Comment: If using python 3.6 and above i prefer f strings, but it is upto user to decide his style

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.6+ offers a new string format.

```
name = "jack"
my_string = f"hello my name is {name}"
```

Answer (score 2):

[format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) function now is stated as the most correct and recommended way to use formatted strings because it is much more [powerful](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) than old strings.

`%` is stated as outdated format.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) you can see examples of old- and new-formatting strings.

P.S. In Python 3.6 were announced new [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 2):

All methods are dependant on which operations you wish to achieve and the efficiency of execution. Currently, the newest and most efficient way to format strings in python was introduced in python 3.6 and looks like:

`f' {}'`

If you wish to format strings, this is currently the best method.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't presume that there is any **best** way to tackle string formatting, I'd say it depends on how much a developer wants his code to be readable.

The formatting with `%` is an old way, but backwards compatible.

Using the `.format(_)` function is the recommended way going forward.

Concatenation of strings together is usually very hard to read or to grasp as to what the final string is supposed to be.

I personally always use `.format` option, also because it allows to name the variables inside the curly brackets. For example

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
time_now = "Time: '{time}'".format(time=now)
```

In this way it gives a more general variable name inside the string, so that everybody knows what the input variable is about.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know about the naming option. I've read the answers and new F Strings sound interesting. Will make some research on it :)